# Downloading Dropbox folder with curl/requests

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm storing two files in a folder on Dropbox and I want to download the folder as a zipped file using `requests`, just as I would if I were downloading it from Dropbox's GUI. I've created a Share Link and am trying to reach it with requests:

`requests.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/folderkeyasdsadlksad?dl=1')`

But I get a `Response <404>`, presumably because I'm trying to access a folder, which has no file extension, rather than a file. How do I download the zipped file?

Comment: is this link working in web browser when you logged in and logged out? I tried it in web brower and also get `404`. If it doesn't work in web browser then it can't work in `requests`, `curl`, `wget`, etc.

Comment: That's just a dummy key, not the actual key. I just tried with `dropboxusercontent` (the way you're supposed to download files) and also got a 404 in my browser, but I get a 200 when I use the regular URL. But it's still not downloading.

Comment: if web browser can't download it then you can't download it with `requests`, `curl`, `wget` - simply Dropbox may not have this functionality and you will have to write code which get list of all files in folder and download every file separatelly.

Comment: using dropbox web page I created folder with two files and created this shared link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqd9hpvd177j9up/AABCV3rPlLrNvjEcoYWMmXXXa?dl=1 and I have no problem to download it with `browser`, `curl`, `wget` and `requests`. Maybe you used wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Dropbox shared links to use the `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` host is not officially supported.

If you want to download from shared links programmatically like this, you can use the `www.dropbox.com` host with [the URL parameters documented here](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download).

For example, that would look like this:

```
requests.get('https://www.dropbox.com/s/folderkeyasdsadlksad?dl=1')
```

For links to folders, that will yield a zip download of the folder, after the redirect(s).